# Maven Shade includes slf4j-log4j12 despite being explicitly excluded from POM

Tags: java, maven, slf4j, apache-storm

My overall goal is to write a Storm Topology (version 0.9.4). I am using Maven Shade version 2.4.3 to generate the uber JAR but despite my efforts I keep getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError

When I run the Topology.

After some reading, I excluded `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` from the POM (it was included in several nested dependencies) and ran

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to ensure that `slf4j-log4j12` was NOT in the tree.

However, when I run Maven Shade, build the JAR, execute:

```
jar -tvf target\StormTopology.jar | grep slf4j
```

I can still see the classes from `slf4j-log4j12` :

```
     0 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/
   113 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/pom.properties
  1644 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/pom.xml
  1011 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 org/slf4j/helpers/NOPMakerAdapter.class
     0 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 org/slf4j/impl/
  6686 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 org/slf4j/impl/Log4jLoggerAdapter.class
  1314 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 org/slf4j/impl/Log4jLoggerFactory.class
  1932 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 org/slf4j/impl/Log4jMDCAdapter.class
  1962 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
  1221 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 org/slf4j/impl/StaticMDCBinder.class
  1376 Wed Jan 20 15:39:48 EST 2016 org/slf4j/impl/StaticMarkerBinder.class
```

I have attempted to exclude `slf4j-log4j12` from the artifact :

```
<artifactSet>
 <excludes>
  <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:*</exclude>
 </excludes>
</artifactSet>
```

I have also attempted to filter `slf4j-log4j12` :

```
<filters>
 <filter>
  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
   <excludes>
    <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:*</exclude>
   </excludes>
 </filter>
</filter>
```

I guess I do not understand some fundamental function that Maven Shade is performing because I cannot figure out why `slf4j-log4j12` keeps being included in my uber JAR.

Edit #1 : Added full Maven

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <finalName>${package.jar.name}</finalName>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Below also please find the results of mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ mc-interop-cop-ibs-interface ---
[INFO] com.vistronix:mc-interop-cop-ibs-interface:jar:1.9.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.9.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.5.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- clj-time:clj-time:jar:0.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- compojure:compojure:jar:1.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:core.incubator:jar:0.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:tools.macro:jar:0.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- clout:clout:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- ring:ring-core:jar:1.1.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- hiccup:hiccup:jar:0.3.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- ring:ring-devel:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  +- clj-stacktrace:clj-stacktrace:jar:0.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- ring:ring-jetty-adapter:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  +- ring:ring-servlet:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:tools.logging:jar:0.2.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:math.numeric-tower:jar:0.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.clojure:tools.cli:jar:0.2.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:carbonite:jar:1.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.3.5:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.disruptor:disruptor:jar:2.10.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:jar:0.9.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:provided
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.13:provided
[INFO] |  \- jline:jline:jar:2.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:jar:0.8.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.101tec:zkclient:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.storm:storm-kafka:jar:0.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.16.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.16.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-kafka:jar:2.16.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:jar:0.8.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:0.8.2.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.vistronix:mc-interop-server-common:jar:1.9.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netcentric.evr:evr-server-data:jar:1.9.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.symantec:SymJavaAPI:jar:4.3.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.accumulo:accumulo-core:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.accumulo:accumulo-fate:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.accumulo:accumulo-start:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.accumulo:accumulo-trace:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-vfs2:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-api:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svnexe:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svn-commons:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- regexp:regexp:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6:system
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.23:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.23:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:cloudera-jets3t:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sf.kosmosfs:kfs:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.0a:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.0.0-cdh4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.qpid:qpid-client:jar:0.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.qpid:qpid-common:jar:0.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- mil.army.inscom:security-helper:jar:1.0.009:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- mil.army.inscom:classification-util:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jblocks:jblocks-Classification:jar:9.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jblocks:jblocks-StringUtils:jar:7.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jblocks:jblocks-CountryCode:jar:7.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jblocks:jblocks-Iterators:jar:7.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jblocks:jblocks-Containers:jar:8.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- mil.army.inscom:accumulo-classification:jar:1.3.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- jblocks:jblocks-UnitTester:jar:7.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- mil.army.inscom:provenance:jar:1.1.023:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.javacsv:javacsv:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-rasterizer:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-js:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.sanselan:sanselan:jar:0.97-incubator:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.docx4j:docx4j:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-svg11:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-xslfo:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-xmldsig-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.engio:mbassador:jar:1.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.arnx:wmf2svg:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netcentric.evr:evr-server-common:jar:1.9.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.bbn:openmap:jar:5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:jar:1.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- junit:junit-dep:jar:4.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- mil.army.inscom:encryption-utilities:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.0.CR1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.0.CR1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.micromata.jak:JavaAPIforKml:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.hsr:ch.hsr.geohash:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geotools:gt-geometry:jar:10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jsr-275:jsr-275:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-main:jar:10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-api:jar:10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- java3d:vecmath:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  \- org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- jgridshift:jgridshift:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.vistronix:mc-interop-server-common-data:jar:1.9.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.futureskies.dci:dci-api:jar:13.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.futureskies.dci:dci-shared:jar:13.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.futureskies.dci:ltxmllib:jar:13.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.futureskies.dci:thrift:jar:13.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
```

Comment: Can you show the portion of your pom where you are configuring the shade plugin?  I made a minimal pom with no dependencies at all but used shade to create a (very small) uber jar, and the result did *not* include `slf4j-log4j12`.

Comment: Full Maven Shade configuration added. I also included the output of `mvn dependency:tree` for reference.

Comment: When something like this happens to me it is usually caused by an unclean build - i.e that files from a previous build/dependency configuration linger around, and accidentally get added to the final artefact. Did you try running a clean build?

Comment: @sfThomas ... yes. Every time I build this JAR it's `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately my problem was resolved in a way that was beyond my control. One of the dependent JAR files was updated to remove the reference to `slf4j-log4j12`. This means that it did not need to be excluded from the Storm Topology project. Once this update was made, the problem went away.

So either it was a transient issue or there is a bug *somewhere* that I cannot spend any more time troubleshooting.